# Genus terminology

Tags: terminology

Why is the number of holes of a surface called genus? 
It is called "genre" in French and "Geschlecht" in German.

Just out of curiosity, I used Google to find the answer but couldn't find anything yet.

Comment: See [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics : Genus](http://jeff560.tripod.com/g.html); the origin seems to be German.

Comment: It is a way of characterizing a collection of (topologically) similar surfaces.

Comment: I always imagined that the usage was derived from the Classification of Species (as in Genus/species).  After all, topological genus was introduced as a classification tool.  Mind you, I have no idea where the Evolution people came up with the word.

Comment: @Lulu - Exactly; "evolution people" derived it from the zoologist [Carl Linnaeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Linnaeus) that in turn derived it from Aristotle. But the "root" is the same : classification : male/female, [mammals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammal_classification) etc, [orientable surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics))

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  That certainly makes sense.